# How do I redirect or rewrite specific URLs in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I have the following situation:
I need to permanently redirect the following URLs using the .htaccess:

1. https://its4you.gr/web-apps to https://its4you.gr/ypiresies/web-apps
2. https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-epaggelmatikou-katalogou https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-epeggelmatikou-katalogou
3. https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidas-blog https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-blog
4. https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidon-mesiton https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidas-real-estate

If I use Redirect rules then I have the folowing code:

```
Redirect 301 /web-apps https://its4you.gr/ypiresies/web-apps
Redirect 301 /web-apps/kataskevi-epaggelmatikou-katalogou https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-epeggelmatikou-katalogou
Redirect 301 /web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidas-blog https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-blog
Redirect 301 /web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidon-mesiton https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidas-real-estate
```

What the above code does is to redirect https://its4you.gr/web-apps to https://its4you.gr/ypiresies/web-apps but the rest are wrong because for all of them I get the message
"The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

The host told me that the Rewrite rules have higher priority of the Redirect rules so I tried using Rewrite rules wiout any success.

How can I redirect the above URLs the right way?

Comment: The Redirect directive only does prefix matching against the given path - so `Redirect 301 /web-apps ...` applies to _all_ URL paths beginning with `/web-apps`. With RedirectMatch or RewriteRule you can use regular expressions, and _anchor_ your pattern to the start and/or end of your test subject.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply could you write for me how I could redirect 1. https://its4you.gr/web-apps to https://its4you.gr/ypiresies/web-apps and 2. https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-istoselidas-blog https://its4you.gr/web-apps/kataskevi-blog ? What would the regular expressions I could use and how will the final statemets should be so I can try them? Thanks